# String splitter for as long as there is something in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have this code to split strings. Currently if the counter is equal to the number of rows on which data is present, it will run properly. However, this number of rows is variable. How do I make the for loop run for as long there is data?

```
Sub SplitToColumns()

    Range("A1").Select
    For Counter = 0 To 100 Step 1

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

get the row number of the last populated row in column A. (Replace with the column of your choice). Then use that row number in the for-loop, but start with 1, not with zero. Remove the debug.print if no longer required.

```
Sub SplitToColumns()
Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print rowCount

    Range("A1").Select
    For Counter = 1 To rowCount Step 1

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

There are several other ways to make this code more efficient. For example, you don't need to select the cell before you do a TextToColumns. In fact, you can do a TextToColumns on a range of cells, you don't need to loop through all the cells in the range.

Use the technique above to get the row number of the last row, and then build a range starting in A1 and extending to column A, last populated row number.

Then perform a TextToColumns on the whole range, all in one go. Much, much faster than looping!!!

```
Sub SplitToColumns()
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:A" & rowCount).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=.Range("A1"), _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=True, _
            Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I prefer the second set of code. (without the `.Activate`) :) Also not in favor of using `.Select` in a loop. In fact not in favor of using `.Select` at all. :) Also `Step 1` in `For` loop is not required...

Comment: Thanks, Sid. Re activate: if used in a Sheet module, the result of the TextToColumns will be placed wherever the active cell happens to be (at least that's what Excel 2013 did in my tests). Hence activating A1. Try it without and select another cell before running it.

Comment: True and hence one needs to specify the exact destination in `Destination:=` :)

Comment: I made a small change to your code. If you are not happy, feel free to roll back the changes. Now no matter whichever sheet is active, it will output the result to the correct sheet only. :)

Comment: That's fine, @SiddharthRout. I normally run simple stuff through sheet module only, since it's less staging work. I get lazy after 9 pm......

Comment: How do i convert the line rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row to give the number of columns that have data? I tried LastColumn = Cells(Columns.Count, "2").End(xlLeft).Column, but it returns error when i run it.

Comment: That would be like this: `LastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` - The Cells() function takes the parameters `row` and `column` in that order, so you need to pass the row number first, but as a number, not as text. And the End() function parameter is `xlToLeft`. It's inconsistent compared to `xlUp`, but where would all the fun be if things were consistent?